# My htacess rewrite is working but how to set redirection also

Tags: url-rewrite-module

I rewrite URL

```
https://myareanurse.com/?page=about-us
```

to

```
https://myareanurse.com/about-us
```

using below code

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ index.php?page=about-us [NC,L]
```

Its working correct but when I open old URL that also open.
I need if I open old URL than its redirect to new URL.

Comment: I tried this one:
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^page=about-us$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://myareanurse.com/about-us   [R=301,L]

Comment: but output is:
https://myareanurse.com/about-us?page=about-us

adding ?page=about-us in end